# sudo apt update

Tags: apt, updates

please forgive me if im asking wrong question in the wrong place, i recently installed nala but uninstalled after being worried about using it as I have just switched to Ubuntu after 30 yrs windows user. So i get error message after uninstalling nala and im wondering if i removed nala wrong? (because i picked top 3 repositories while setting up nala) now im getting this:

```
sudo apt update -y
[sudo] password for frostbite: 
Err:2 http://mirror.deace.id/ubuntu jammy InRelease                            
  400  Bad Request [IP: 104.247.81.54 80]
Hit:3 https://deb.imaginary.stream jammy InRelease                             
Hit:4 https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable InRelease             
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]      
Hit:1 http://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/ubuntu jammy InRelease                    
Hit:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                      
Hit:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease              
Hit:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease            
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [41.5 kB]
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [18.6 kB]
Ign:11 https://mirror.vcu.edu/pub/gnu+linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease             
Ign:11 https://mirror.vcu.edu/pub/gnu+linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease             
Ign:11 https://mirror.vcu.edu/pub/gnu+linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:11 https://mirror.vcu.edu/pub/gnu+linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Could not handshake: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated. [IP: 128.172.15.65 443]
Reading package lists... Done                   
E: Failed to fetch http://mirror.deace.id/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  400  Bad Request [IP: 104.247.81.54 80]
E: The repository 'http://mirror.deace.id/ubuntu jammy InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: https://deb.imaginary.stream/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://deb.imaginary.stream jammy InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

Once again Im sorry if this wrong place once again and thank you in advance for any advice on this matter. I love Linux and just want to not screw it up.

Comment: Can you run the command `sudo apt update` and post the output by editing the question? https://askubuntu.com/posts/1461074/edit

Comment: when i enter the whole thing it says im not eligable to post links, i guess there are links in the terminal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apt repository is not signed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1322959/apt-repository-is-not-signed)

Comment: You can if you use code formatting. On the desktop version of this site, you can get text marked up as code by pasting it, selecting the pasted block, and typing ctrl-K.

Comment: i got it up as is just copied as html

Comment: not sure tiiplee, i edited so you can see more. thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apt-key deprecation warning when updating system](https://askubuntu.com/q/1398344/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'xxx' doesn't support architecture 'i386'](https://askubuntu.com/q/741410/)

Answer (score 2):

Take the error message:

```
Err:2 http://mirror.deace.id/ubuntu jammy InRelease                            
  400  Bad Request [IP: 104.247.81.54 80]
```

Simply try that URL in your web browser: http://mirror.deace.id/ubuntu

You will quickly see that the mirror does not exist.

Open "Software & Updates" -> Other Software -> Delete that source.

Answer (score 0):

Take the error message:

```
Err:11 https://mirror.vcu.edu/pub/gnu+linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Could not handshake: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated. [IP: 128.172.15.65 443]
```

One simple solution is to edit the source. It does not need to be https. It can be plain http, since each package is individually signed.

Comment: Hey, please consider combining your answers and deleting one of them.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi maybe, but the question includes two independent problems and therefore should be two separate questions. Our alternatives are two simple answers that can each help future readers, or one complex answer that is unlikely to help anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems.

1. the deace.id mirror does not exist.
   Remove the problematic repositories: You can try to remove the problematic repositories from the sources.list file of your system. To do this, open the /etc/apt/sources.list file in a text editor and remove the lines that reference the problematic repositories. Then save the file and run the sudo apt update command again.

`sudo apt-get clean all && sudo apt-get update`

2. no signature key for deace.id
   Which is obsolete with the delete.
3. legacy keyring

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys <key_id from imaginary.stream>`